# Access all variables by their names of specific object in class

Tags: python

I have two python classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1 = param1

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

Now I have an instance of B and need to access param1, I can just write `b.a.param1`. But the goal is to omit the 'a' part, so access this param with `b.param1`. I could add property to class B, but I am searching for generic solution - when A class has a lot variables. Is it possible? And would it be clean solution?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

Comment: If you simply want `B` to have `A`'s attributes, have you considered inheritance? `class B(A)`. Then you will be able to do `b.param1`. We need more information to really help

Comment: @Tomerikoo Unfortunately inheritance ins't a solution. The need for that is because we extract a lot parameters from B class to A class and we can't break old code which uses b.param1 accessing

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually it will work, but isn't that bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant option and probably a bad practice but you can copy all the attributes of `a` to be attributes of `b` using `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
import inspect

class A:
    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1 = param1

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        variables = [i for i in dir(a) if not inspect.ismethod(i) and i[:2] != '__']
        for var in variables:
            setattr(self, var, getattr(a, var))
```

This way you can access `a`'s attributes directly:

```
a = A(1)
b = B(a)
b.param1
```

which will return

> 1

Comment: Thanks, both solutions (yours and with __getatrr_) satisfy my needs!